# jsrcollpane scroll to specific div when link is clicked

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

How can I get jsrcollpane to scroll to a specific div when a link is clicked? I have IDs for divs in a scroll pane and links on the page that I want to control the scrolling. I have found how to scroll a specific amount of pixels, but not how to scroll to a divs coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You cane use the API of jQueryscrollpane
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html

There ar the method `scrollToElement` or `scrollTo` or `scrollY`
Example:

```
 api.scrollToElement('#elem', false, true, 115);
```